# How to upload image in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress, I am currently creating a plugin which is get the message and image and store it in database. I learn wpdb class to store data to database, But i still can't know how to move and upload file and store in also in folder and media library. Please help me i tried codes which i get at wordpress.org but still cant upload image to media library. If you cant tell me please reference to learn admin-ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Get an array containing the current upload directory’s path and url.

```
wp_upload_dir( string $time = null, bool $create_dir = true, bool $refresh_cache = false )
```

You can find more on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

Comment: Great ! Then Give me Up vote by clicking on ▲ and Accept my answer by clicking on check symbol ✔ on left side :)